# Anko alert text color show wrong

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, anko

I am showing the alert dialog with a message and ok button. but ok button color and text of the button is same

```
context!!.alert ("this test message for the dialog aleat"){
            okButton { context!!.toast("yeah it ok") }
        }.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like problem with styles of button and text.

Comment: I have used  the default style.

Comment: What are your "colorPrimary", colorPrimaryDark" and "colorAccent" in AppTheme ?

Comment: follwoing  colors are use    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>

Comment: @eurosecom thanks for ur help. actually, the problem is in new material style. I had remove it and it working fine.

Comment: @AnilUgale May I know how you solve it? remove what?

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this using following code. working for me

```
     getContext()?.alert("me") {
            also {
                ctx.setTheme(R.style.CustomAlertDialog)
            }
            okButton {  getContext()!!.toast("Done") }
        }!!.show()
```

theme changes is

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/CustomAlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/btnStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="btnStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the perfect solution:

Use `Theme.AppCompat...` in `styles.xml` rather than `Theme.MaterialComponents...`.